# Custom regression analysis in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel.  The first column is the values for the independent variable.  The other columns are sets of data for the dependent variable.  I want to fit each data set to the langmuir equation: y=Ax/(1+Bx).  Is there a way to write a function that will find A and B for each column?

Comment: I think it's more likely [stats.se] than [so] question

Comment: I know how to do it mathematically.  It becomes a programming question, because I have over a hundred sets of data and I want to fit them all quickly and conveniently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Excel with the Solver plug-in.  You'll need to add the following to your sheet:

1. Two cells that contain your changing A and B coefficients for the regression;
2. A column of length equal to that of your dependent variable data. Fill down this formula in the column: `=$F$2*A2/(1+$F$3*A2)`, where F2 and F3 are your A and B coefficients, and A2 is the first independent variable value.
3. Another cell that contains the Residual for your regression.  I used the RMSE with this array formula: `{=SQRT(AVERAGE((B2:B28-C2:C28)^2))}` (Enter the formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.) Here B2:B28 is the dependent variable data you are fitting, and C2:C28 is the data for the regression function.

Now you are set up to use Solver to fit your regression function.  Set Solver to minimize the residual while changing the A and B coefficients.

You should be able to handle all your data sets programmatically from here on out with a procedure similar to the following:

1. Make sure regression column matches length of your data.
2. Change residual formula to match present data of interest.
3. Set seed values for A and B.
4. Run solver.
5. Record coefficient values and residual somewhere else.
6. Repeat.